# Idiomatic way of expressing the action to exchange the roles of two objects?

Tags: expressions

What is the idiomatic way of saying exchange the roles of two objects?

> For example, let A play offense and B play defense, and then _____ ,
> let B play offense and A play defense.

-- EDIT --

I thought about using "exchange roles". But it sounds a bit technical. Googling it led me to documentations of Microsoft Exchange Server for some operations about user roles there.

Ideally, I am looking for something expressive enough so that when I write:

> For example, let A play offense and B play defense, and then _____.

The reader/audience could infer the "let B play offense and A play defense" part.

Comment: Let's switch it up: You go first. What expressions did you consider? We are not actually in the business of producing lists.

Comment: I guess swap roles, switch positions, etc, aren't idioms, so I'm at a loss as to what you want.

Comment: ... and then *reverse them.* There is no need to continue the sentence with an explanation of what 'reverse' means.

Comment: *Switch* is not an idiom, but it is idiomatic. Must we really look these up for the OP?

Comment: *Switch* is the first word that came to my mind as well.

Comment: 'Change, swap, switch…' all seem obvious. Either way in my view word, phrase or expression requests should be promoted to their own specialised community, perhaps named 'Vocabulary.'

Answer (score 0):

*Swap* would work, but **switch it up**, as proposed by Yosef, or **switch up**, would be the most idiomatic way to say this in the context of something like a soccer practice, in the US.

If the coach wants to do a rotation, and shout something short each time a player should move to a new position, they would probably say "switch it up" in the initial instructions, and shorten that to "switch" or "rotate" subsequently.

If the context is a scrimmage or a game, then the instructions would be more complicated:

> A, you sub in for B on defense, and B, can you play goalie for one quarter?

(Young people might be nervous about playing goalie -- sometimes you get kicked by accident.)

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/switch-up):

> **switch something up**
>
> *phrasal verb with switch verb*
> *informal mainly US*
>
> to change something, usually in a way that improves it:
>
> *You might want to switch up a recipe you've made several times by trying other flavors.*
>
> *I love the way they switched it up by playing the song acoustically.*

Comment: What gets me is that the one question no one asked is: Is this about people or objects? But the comments are now locked.

Comment: @Lambie - Oh.  I was assuming it was people on offense and defense.  Ah, I see it now: "two objects."  Well, hopefully, OP will straighten me out if I was *off base*!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate: "occurring or succeeding by turns" MW

Let A play offense and B play defense, and then alternate.

Answer (score 0):

“Okay, let’s **flip it around**.”

Lots of hits on google. Lots of examples in the great corpus of English writings, like this one:

https://glosbe.com/en/en/flip%20it%20around